# Why can we say $0\leq\sin^2(x)\leq 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I often see instructors write:

$0\leq\sin^2(x)\leq 1$

Why is this valid?
Isn't it supposed to be between $1$ and $-1$?

Comment: $\sin^2 x = (\sin x)^2$, so it's non-negative.

Comment: You have $0 \le \sin^2 x \le 1$.

Comment: I guess you mean it is supposed to be between -1 and 1. Well, because for $t\in [-1,1]$ we have $t^2\in [0,1]$ (set $t=\sin x$ in your case).

Comment: In the future, please use LaTeX markup and avoid outside link by typing the equations in. I've made the appropriate edits for you and you'll see them once they are approved by a mod.

Comment: I should also add, I like this question. Little details like this seem obvious to some, but really do trip one up occasionally. Always good to ask.

Answer (score 5):

Because
$\sin^2(x) \ge 0$,
$\cos^2(x) \ge 0$,
and
$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)
= 1
$.

Comment: Isn't that what the op asked.  Why is $sin^2 (x) \ge 0$?  The op is under the impresion it should be $sin^2 (x) \ge -1$.  So this doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: The original question asked why $0 < \sin^2(x) < 1$ for $x \not= 0$ but has now been changed to something else.

The note in the question is not correct: if $x = \pi/2$, then $\sin^2 x = 1$, and if $x = \pi$, then $\sin^2 x = 0$, so $0 < \sin^2 x < 1$ fails to hold true in those cases.

What is true, through, is that $0 \leq \sin^2 x \leq 1$ for all $x$ (including $x = 0$): since the square of any real number is non-negative, you have $0 \leq \sin^2 x$. On the other hand, if a real number $y$ satisfies $0 \leq y \leq 1$, then $y^2 \leq 1$ (since, for instance, $y \mapsto y^2$ is increasing on $[0, \infty)$, and $0^2 = 0$, $1^2 = 1$). Recalling that $\sin x \leq 1$ for all $x$, this implies that also $\sin^2 x \leq 1$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 2):

If you plot the to graphs it would be easier for you to see the boundaries.

[image: Graphs of both sin(x) and sin^2(x)]

Answer (score 1):

$x \in \mathbb R$ then $x^2 \ge 0$.

If $|x| \le 1$ then $x^2 = |x|^2 = |x||x| \le |x|*1 = |x| \le 1$.

So as $-1 \le \sin x \le 1$, it follows $(\sin x)^2 \le 1$.  And as $(\sin x)^2 \ge 0$, $0 \le \sin^2 x \le 1$.